# grid system with floats and max-width issue

Tags: html, css

Could someone have a look at my code and tell me what needs to be fixed to make my div elastic without using flexbox. Here is my [code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LrofE)

```
h1 {
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  background-color:blue; 
  padding:1em 0;

  .row {
    background-color:gold; 
    padding:1em 0 0;

    [class*="col-"] {
      border: 1px solid red;
      box-sizing: border-box; 
      float:left;
      width:100%;
    }
  }
  .row:last-child {
    padding-bottom:1em
  }
  .row:before,
  .row:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
  }
  .row:after {
    clear:both;
  }
}

.container {
  $base_width: 8px;
  max-width: $base_width * 8 * 12 - $base_width * 2;
  margin:0 auto;

  .row{
    margin:0 -#{$base_width};    
    /*display:flex;    
    align-items: middle;*/

    @for $i from 1 through 12 {
      .col-#{$i} {
        max-width: $base_width * 8 * $i - $base_width * 2;
        margin: 0 $base_width;         
      }
    }    
  }
}

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
  <div class="col-6"><h1>1/4</h1></div>
 <div class="col-6">1/4</div>

    </div>  
    <div class="row">
 <div class="col-3">1/4</div>
 <div class="col-3">1/4</div>
 <div class="col-3">1/4</div>
 <div class="col-3">1/4</div>

    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: you mean like this? http://codepen.io/Nico_O/pen/hbuwi your question not really that clear.

Comment: What *exactely* Do you mean by elastic? Should all be 100% width? Or should all shrink for smaller window? Or resonsive?

Comment: no the inner divs or the .row class should be elastic when the browser is resized.

Comment: flexible when when the browsser is resized so the stretch

Comment: like this demo http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AtHGk when you resize it the divs shrink larger and smaller

Answer (score 1):

Try it with a different `$base_width`

```
$base_width: 100% / 12 / 8;
```

http://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/cgLtF

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, changing your inner divs to percentage width gives the layout you want, i.e.

```
max-width: 23%;
margin: 0 1%;
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ArKEo

Comment: Now that ruins the grid flow of 1/4 and 1/2 flow in the rows class

Comment: Sorry, it was the 1/4's written in all the cells that confused me. Is this what you're looking for? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KHstz